# MessageBox case for Ok an Cancel?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

how can I make "cases" for the following code:

```
win32api.MessageBox(None,
                    "This Program Will do THIS:\n"
                    "blablabla",
                    "programtitler",
                    win32con.MB_OKCANCEL | win32con.MB_ICONQUESTION)
```

for example

if select ok, do THIS, if select cancel, do THAT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be something like this. (C#)

```
    int result = win32api.MessageBox(None,
                        "This Program Will do THIS:\n"
                        "blablabla",
                        "programtitler",
                        win32con.MB_OKCANCEL | win32con.MB_ICONQUESTION)

    switch (result)
    {
        case win32con.MB_IDOK: 
        //OK Selected.
        //put 'ok' code here.
        break;
        case win32con.MB_IDCANCEL:
        //Cancel Selected.
        //put 'Cancel' code here.
        break;
    }
```

Not versed in python, but you should be able to just use if statements instead of a switch, like so:

```
    if result == win32con.MB_IDOK:
        //put 'ok' code here
    elif result == win32con.MB_IDCANCEL:
        //put 'cancel' code here
```

Comment: I would +1 this, except what you wrote isn't Python.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), return value will be value of selected button. So you will need to check it.